# Output a jquery variable inside html?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code, which displays the text "Test" over the image (with the help of some CSS). Instead of "Test" I would like to display the filename here. The `.attr('alt', url)` will display the full url to the file selected. I have tried to put the `url` inside the `<span></span>` without success.
How do I put the variable `url` inside html? And how do I remove the full URL and just keep the filename and extension? Something like removing everything until the last `/`maybe could work?

```
   var img = jQuery( '<img><h3><span>Test</span></h3>' )
 .attr('src', "/img/video.png")
 .attr('alt', url)
```

This is the complete script:

```
function showVideoPreview(url) {
    var container = jQuery( '#background-video-preview' );
    container.empty();
    if (url) {
        var img = jQuery( '<img><h3><span>Test</span></h3>' )
            .attr('src', "/img/video.png")
            .attr('alt', url)
            .click(function(){
                jQuery('#background-video-button').click();
            });
        container.append(img);
        jQuery('#background-video-remove').show();
    } else {
        jQuery('#background-video-remove').hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use template string (`you text ${ variable }`) remember is with (``) very important

```
function showVideoPreview(url) {
    var container = jQuery( '#background-video-preview' );
    container.empty();
    if (url) {
        var img = jQuery( `<img><h3><span>Test ${url}</span></h3>` )
            .attr('src', "/img/video.png")
            .attr('alt', url)
            .click(function(){
                jQuery('#background-video-button').click();
            });
        container.append(img);
        jQuery('#background-video-remove').show();
    } else {
        jQuery('#background-video-remove').hide();
    }
}
```